# send file to serial port in python

Tags: xmodem

i am trying to send the file below '105.8k' to my energy meter.
i am using the xmodem example from pypi but i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Py\mainpy.py", line 68, in <module>
    status = modem.send(f, retry=3)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xmodem\__init__.py", line 270, in send
    char = self.getc(1)
  File "C:\py\mainpy.py", line 62, in getc
    return ser.read(size) or None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

the code i use:

### send file to port###

ser = serialPortCombobox.get().split(" ")[0]

def getc(size, timeout=1):
    return ser.read(size) or None
def putc(data, timeout=1):
    return ser.write(data)
modem = XMODEM(getc, putc)

f = open('105.8k', 'rb')
status = modem.send(f, retry=3)
ser.close()
stream.close()

thank you for your help.
```

Comment: Because `ser` is a string

Comment: so  how can i fix please?